# Null Pointer Exceptions Without Apparent Reason

Tags: java

StackOverflow. I am attempting to make a program that uses a text menu to to a multitude of things to manipulate a single string. One of the methods turns the string into an array of strings. This works fine. However, all of the methods that manipulate it as an array(one prints it out, one reverses the word order, and one sorts them using an exchange sorting method) return a NullPointerException when called. I have looked all through the code and do not see where it is coming from. Here is the .Java file containing all of the code. My problem is only happening when I call the printArray(), reverse(), and sort() methods, near the bottom. Any and all help is appreciated. Sorry for the sloppy code, I have not cleaned it up yet.

Code:

```
  /*
Computer Programming Lab 11
Jim Kimble
3 Mar 2013

Work with strings and implementing a menu.

Acknowledgements:
Uses main structure of HUTPanel as designed at UMU, 2002-2012
*/

import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class HUTPanel extends JPanel
{
/***************************************************
 * Class-level data members should be declared here.
 ***************************************************/
int numVowels;
String[] words;
String str;
String vowels;
String menuChoice;
String oString = "A tong lime ago, a daggy shog bossed a cridge over a pillmond,\n"
                 +"When in the course of human events\n"
                 +"Mary had a little lamb.\n"
                 +"The girls' basketball team repeated as tournament champion this weekend.";




public HUTPanel(JFrame frame)
{

    // Set panel background color
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setLayout(null);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(810, 410));

    /***************************
     * Now add your code below:
     ***************************/

    //  Create a frame around this panel.
    frame.setTitle("Computer Programming Lab/Program # 11");
    frame.getContentPane().add(this);

    str = "A tong lime ago, a daggy shog bossed a cridge over a pillmond,\n"
          +"When in the course of human events\n"
          +"Mary had a little lamb.\n"
          +"The girls' basketball team repeated as tournament champion this weekend.";

    System.out.println("Lab 11: Text Manipulation");
    //getTheText();
    System.out.println("The string is: '"+str+"'.");

    handleTheMenu();

} // end of constructor

/*************************
  * Add your methods here:
  *************************/

// Get a text sequence from the keyboard and put it in str
public void getTheText()
{
    Boolean inputDone = false;

    while (!inputDone)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter your text:  ");
        inputDone = grabText();
    }

}

private Boolean grabText()
{

    try {
            BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            menuChoice = inputReader.readLine();
            return true;
    }
    catch(IOException e) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Error reading input. Please try again.");
    }

    return false;

}

public void handleTheMenu()
{   
    int choice = -1;
    Boolean OK;

    while (choice != 0)
    {
        choice = -1;

        System.out.println("Menu:");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("  1. Count the vowels"); //"There are ... vowels in the text."
        System.out.println("  2. Remove all letter e's"); //then print it.
        System.out.println("  3. Replace all t's with '+'"); //then print it
        System.out.println("  4. Search for a requested word (will reset the string)"); //Does 'word' exist in the text?
        System.out.println("  5. Print the words on individual lines"); 
        System.out.println("  6. Reset the string.");//Reset the string to the original
        System.out.println("  7. Put the words in an array"); //then print it
        System.out.println("  8. Reverse the text word order"); //then print it
        System.out.println("  9. Sort the words in an array"); //Once the words are put into an array
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("  0 to quit --> ");

        OK = grabText();

        if (OK)
        {
            try
            {
                choice = Integer.parseInt(menuChoice);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Not a number; please try again.");
                System.out.println();
            }

            switch(choice)
            {
                case 0:  System.out.println();
                         System.out.println("Thank you.");
                         break;
                case 1:  countVowels();
                         break;
                case 2:  removeAllEs();                             
                         break;
                case 3:  changeTToPlus();
                         break;
                case 4:  find();
                         break;
                case 5:  listWords();
                         break;
                case 6:  reset();
                         break;
                case 7:  makeArray();
                         break;
                case 8:  reverse();
                         break;
                case 9:  sort();
                         break;
                default: System.out.println("Not a valid choice; please try again.");    
            }
        }
    }
}

private void countVowels() {
    //count the vowels in str
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    numVowels = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < vowels.length(); i ++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
            if (str.charAt(j) == vowels.charAt(i)) {
                numVowels += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The string has " + numVowels + " vowels in it.");
}

private void removeAllEs() {
    String str3 = str.replace('e', ' '); 
    System.out.print(str3);
    str = str3;
}

private void changeTToPlus() {
 String str2 = str.replace('t', '+');
 System.out.println(str2);
 str = str2;
}

private void find() {
    str = oString;
    getTheText();
    if(str.indexOf(menuChoice) != -1) 
    {
        System.out.println("The word " +menuChoice+  " is at index " +str.indexOf(menuChoice));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The word " +menuChoice+ " is not in the string.");
    }
}

private void listWords() {
    int pos = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(i > -1)
    {
        i = str.indexOf(' ', pos);
        if (i > -1)
        {
        System.out.println(str.substring(pos, i));
        pos = i + 1;
        }
    }
}


private void reset() {
    str = oString;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("String reset.");
    System.out.println();
}

private void makeArray() {
    int n = 1;
    String[] words = new String[n];
    int pos = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(j > -1)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            n += 1;
            j = str.indexOf(' ', pos);
            if (j > -1)
            {
              words[i] = str.substring(pos, j);
              pos = j + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    //printArray();
}
//***FIX***
private void printArray() {
      for (int k = 0; k < words.length -1; k++){
          System.out.println(words[k]);
      }
  }

//***FIX***
private void reverse() {
    int i = 0;
    int j = words.length - 1;
    String temp;
    while (i < j){
        temp = words[i];
        words[i] = words[j];
        words[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}

private void sort() {
    String temp = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) {
            int x = words[i].compareTo(words[j]);
            if (x > 0) {
                temp = words[i];
                words[i] = words[j];
                words[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int p = 0; p < words.length -1; p++) {
        System.out.println(words[p]);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: please show stacktrace

Comment: Most likely you are trying to call the methods before calling other methods which set the `words` variable..

Comment: I'm new to this. How do I find the stacktrace? I'm using NetBeans 7.2.1, if it makes a difference.

Comment: In the console you will find a whole shitload of red lines. That is what they are asking for. Like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/images/thread-dump-screen.png

Comment: @Teja Kantamneni, the error in the reverse() method is at the line that says  int j = words.length - 1;... The same, or a similar declaration is true for the other methods.

Comment: @user1191339 Please read/try the solution of the proposed answers. You're focusing more on the problem than a solution.

Comment: @PSR:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at HUTPanel.reverse(HUTPanel.java:256)
 at HUTPanel.handleTheMenu(HUTPanel.java:154)
 at HUTPanel.<init>(HUTPanel.java:60)
 at ProgApp.main(ProgApp.java:35)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, I have.

Answer (score 3):

You Error is here:

```
private void makeArray() {
    int n = 1;
    String[] words = new String[n];//At This line you are creating local array words.The instance variable words is still null. 
    int pos = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(j > -1)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            n += 1;
            j = str.indexOf(' ', pos);
            if (j > -1)
            {
              words[i] = str.substring(pos, j);
              pos = j + 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

use:

`words = new String[n];` instead of `String[] words = new String[n];`

As mentioned by *Luiggi Mendoza* in the comment section, the local variable `words` defined within `makeArray` method is [shadowing](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15) the instance variable `words` defined within `HUTPanel` class.
***As side note*** I want to point out the unnecessary creation of new `BufferedReader` objects in  method `grabText()` each time you are calling it in `getTheText()`. It would be much efficient if your make `inputReader` an instance variable in your class , and instantiate it once within the `constructor` using  `inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`. This way your `grabText` method becomes like this :

```
private Boolean grabText()
{

    try {
            //No more new object creation for BufferedReader for each call of this method. 
            menuChoice = inputReader.readLine();
            return true;
    }
    catch(IOException e) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Error reading input. Please try again.");
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: The error is due to [shadowing](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15). Looks like that's what you mean.

Comment: @user1191339 : are you still getting Exceptions?

Comment: *the mistake that you have done in your code is called as shadowing*. Shadowing is not a mistake, is a feature that, when misused, generates problems instead of helping programmers. For example (as stated in the link), a good use of shadowing is in setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you always you always start with option 7, so your `words` array gets initialized. This is in fact not something that the user should do. The application should handle it so that the user either can't select other options, or does it automatically.

**Update**: *Vishal K* is correct, but this is still a weak point in your application.